# Android: Prevent network connection through proxy

Tags: android, proxy

I find out that we can change network proxy in an Android device. And I don't want my application is being used in the device that change Proxy setting.

So, is there any way to detect whether an Android phone is using proxy?

Many thanks.

[image: Change Wifi proxy]